# PDF Download gives corrupt PDF php

Tags: php, pdf

I am saving a pdf file, and then attempting to download it using php.
The script seemed to work fine, but all of the sudden not anymore.

Can anybody see what I am missing?

PS: the file I am downloading is only 4.3kb big, so I assume that would be because it is not downloading at all. The actual file size should be bigger than this.

```
$pdf->output(ROOTDIR.'/modules/addons/statement_generator/reports/statement.pdf');
    if($action=='print'){
        $file_name = 'statement.pdf';
        $file_url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/modules/addons/statement_generator/reports/" . $file_name;
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
        readfile($file_url);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine, so the issue is probably somewhere else. Maybe some accidental output before, something slipping and causing headers to be sent. The usual things apply: first: look into your http servers error log file. Next look into your browsers console and examine the request and reply in the network tab. Then open the downloaded file with a simple text editor to look what is inside.

Comment: What PDF library are you using?

Comment: I am using FPDF @BenSwinburne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$pdf->output()` call will already send the PDF to the client. The file will not be saved to your local folder (Didn't you checked at least this?) because you have to pass "F" as the snd parameter.

After that you try to read from an URL (!!!!) that does not exists and which maybe return a nicely styled 404 html response. Two issues here:

1. Why are you using http when you have the local path used some lines above? Use the local path only!
2. The content returned by the URL is append to the already send PDF which ends in a document mixed of PDF and HTML (the 404 response) -> corrupted PDF

Conclusion: Use "F" as the 2nd parameter and use the same path for both writing and reading and not a mix of local path and URL.